# Application not installing on Android simulator

Tags: android

I have developed an Android application. I have implemented all the functionality of the application. When I run the application in emulator it shows this message:

> [2011-02-01 11:36:39 - Test] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
>   [2011-02-01 11:36:39 - Test] Device API version is 9 (Android 2.3)

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

add this to your manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="[your desired api level here]" />
```

Comment: junmats i have added  the above line as mentioned by u

Comment: But now application is crashing... and it showing source not found,,,,What should i do now??

Comment: I have inputted api level 7,,,Junmats,,do u have skype??

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html you can edit your original question and try to include some codes from your manifest so that I can check..

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your problem. I think you forgot to fill the Min SDK Version value when you created your android project. You have to fill the minimum sdk support for your application when the application is first created, if you specify that the it will be automatically added to the manifest file and to the default property file. In this case you have to manually specify the min sdk in the requirement in the manifest and also in the default properties like in manifest  and in the default.propeties you have to add like 'target=android-8'. Then I think it will be corrected